# I want a list of all the William Hill betting shops in the UK

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am trying to obtain a list of all the William Hill Betting shops in the UK using the google places api. However, using the google places api will only let me return up to 60 results. Does anyone know of a way around this or an alternative approach to the problem I am having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The places API has a `pagetoken` optional parameter that is used to return the next set of results.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#find-place-responses

Edit: I didn't realize the you could only get a maximum number of 60 results. To get around this you can search a smaller area that won't have more than 60 results.

You can use a combination of `location` (latitude and longitude) and `radius`. You can create a box and iteratively shift the coordinates left to right and up and down until your entire area is covered. You can use something like [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to help you calculate the coordinates and then send the request to the google places API

Comment: Each page gives you 20 results. Using the pagetoken parameter you can get up to 60 results but I don't think beyond this.

Comment: Looking into it further, you're correct 60 is the max number of with the same query. I think the way around this would be go break your search into grid sections where there wont be more than 60 results in a given area